# Why does this line leak memory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

```
[row setObject:[NSString stringWithCString:value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] forKey:columnName];
```

where row is a NSMutableDictionary..is there a different way to inject this string into my dictionary?

Comment: Who told you that leaks memory?

Comment: I am using my profiling tools and it shows that there is a leak there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this problem before, because the `NSMutableDictionary` owns the object it won't be released until the Dictionary is released.

I would suggest that somewhere in your code an object is being dealloc'd without properly releasing the variables it owns, likely the `NSMutableDictionary *row`.

Comment: so if I have a custom class that contains multiple objects, is it better form to release each active object in that custom class, then release the parent object?

Comment: In each class you alloc/init/copy an object, that class should be responsible for releasing those objects during a dealloc. I had the exact same thing you did, profiler was telling me the code leaked. My problem was that i wasn't releasing a parent object properly so everything beneath it was never dealloc'd.

Comment: Unless of course you are using ARC (Auto Reference Counting) with SDK5.0, then you should have no issue.

Comment: thanks for this tip, i am using ios4, so I will have to go thru and properly release stuff from my custom classes

Answer (score 1):

Profiling tools says that because the string is "autoreleased", so you *could* optimize it by

- putting a NSAutoreleasePool around it
- alloc/init the str then release it
- or just ignore the optimization message.

This is one way:

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[row setObject:str forKey:columnName];
[str release];
```

Comment: Wouldn't the code you provided end up with the NSString object having exactly the same retain count?

Comment: It depends, the autoreleased string in your code wont get free'd until it hits an autorelease pool drain/release, and to profiling tools, that meets the criteria for a warning.  When you release it manually, it is free'd when you release, and the tools consider that as the standard way of coding, but the difference is so negligible that it really doesnt matter in the end.  Your code is a lot quicker to write, read and looks cleaner so I would keep it how you have it, personally.